# How to prevent scripts in Dockerfile from exiting?

Tags: java, docker, dockerfile

My Dockerfile is:

```
FROM maven:3.3.9-jdk-8-alpine as build-env
COPY . /EscomledML
WORKDIR EscomledML
RUN mvn package

FROM openjdk:8-jdk-alpine
WORKDIR /EscomledML
ADD . /EscomledML
ADD ./lib EscomledML/lib
ADD ./config EscomledML/config
ADD ./config EscomledML/home/escomled/escomled_server/config
ADD ./MLScripts EscomledML/MLScripts
ADD target/escomled-machine-learning-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT-jar-with-dependencies.jar EscomledML/lib/escomled-machine-learning-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT-jar-with-dependencies.jar
EXPOSE 8085
RUN ["sh", "EscomledML/MLScripts/escomled_data_grid.sh"]
RUN ["sh", "EscomledML/MLScripts/escomled_dirwatcher.sh"]
RUN ["sh", "EscomledML/MLScripts/escomled_startmap.sh"]
RUN ["sh", "EscomledML/MLScripts/escomled_ml.sh"]
```

The scripts basically add dependency jars to classpath and start the needed classes, ex. "`java ${ARGS} -classpath "${CLASSPATH}" com.escomled.blackboard.main.DataGridServer`".

When I run `docker-compose up --build` I don't get any output from the scripts.

`docker ps -a` returns

```
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE                           COMMAND                  CREATED             STATUS                      PORTS                                        NAMES
ce690dbba3ab        escomled-ml                    "/bin/sh"                2 minutes ago       Exited (0) 2 minutes ago                                                 desktop_escomled-ml_1
```

Comment: Are you running Docker container in background mode? you need to use 'docker-compose up -d' command. also please check logs why it's failing? docker logs container_name. for you it will be 'docker logs desktop_escomled-ml_1'

Comment: `docker logs desktop_escomled-ml_1` doesn't output anything

Answer (score 2):

> #### How to prevent scripts in Dockerfile from exiting?

Regarding `RUN`, you can't / shoudn't.

This is not how it is supposed to work. [`RUN`](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#run) is used at the stages of **building** an image. It is supposed to do task, finish and continue with the next Dockerfile command.

From the docs:

> The `RUN` instruction will execute any commands in a new layer on top of the current image and commit the results. The resulting committed image will be used for the next step in the `Dockerfile`.

---

Scripts that should be running when you start a container can be set by a combination of [`ENTRYPOINT`](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#entrypoint) and [`CMD`](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#cmd) declarations.

Comment: Changed the lines after `EXPOSE` to

`ENTRYPOINT ["sh", "EscomledML/MLScripts/escomled_data_grid.sh"]

CMD ["sh", "EscomledML/MLScripts/escomled_dirwatcher.sh", "&&", "sh", "EscomledML/MLScripts/escomled_startmap.sh", "&&", "sh", "EscomledML/MLScripts/escomled_ml.sh"]`.
The container still exits with code 0.

Comment: I think this answer is correct but the ENTRYPOINT and CMD that you showed here might be wrong, I have posted a simpler example that I can also test it works for me.

Comment: @VentsyMihalov keep in mind that a container is up and running as long as its `PID 1` is running. Your case looks like you have a script as PID 1 and when it exits, the container stops too. Check also this: [Run multiple services in a container](https://docs.docker.com/config/containers/multi-service_container/)

Answer (score 1):

For the below dockerfile:

```
FROM ubuntu:18.04

RUN echo a
CMD ["bash","-c","echo b && echo c; while true; do sleep 5; echo sleep; done"];
```

Run the following command:

```
docker build -t test1 . && docker run test1
```

You can notice:

- `echo a` is executed at build time
- `echo b` and `echo c` and `echo sleep` are executed at runtime

Now you can use a similarly structured COMMAND in your file and it should work.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly each `RUN` line in your original Dockerfile corresponds to a service (that is a process you want to run until Docker container is stopped). The problem is that Docker container requires one master process that runs in the foreground, is started on container start and stopped when container is stopped. Also, when the master process exits (eg. because an exception is thrown) then the container is stopped automatically.

In order to run mutiple processes in a single container you need to use a process manager that will be started by the container and will then start your services, monitor them and restart them in case of failure or a single wrapper script that starts your services and checks if they are alive. Docker [documentation](https://docs.docker.com/config/containers/multi-service_container/) recommends `supervisord`.

In your casethe wrapper would be something like:

```
#!/bin/bash

# Start the first process
/EscomledML/MLScripts/escomled_data_grid.sh -D
status=$?
if [ $status -ne 0 ]; then
  echo "Failed to start escomled_data_grid: $status"
  exit $status
fi

# Start the second process
/EscomledML/MLScripts/escomled_dirwatcher.sh -D
status=$?
if [ $status -ne 0 ]; then
  echo "Failed to start escomled_dirwatcher: $status"
  exit $status
fi

# Start the third process
/EscomledML/MLScripts/escomled_startmap.sh -D
status=$?
if [ $status -ne 0 ]; then
  echo "Failed to start escomled_startmap: $status"
  exit $status
fi

# Start the fourth process
/EscomledML/MLScripts/escomled_ml.sh -D
status=$?
if [ $status -ne 0 ]; then
  echo "Failed to start escomled_ml: $status"
  exit $status
fi

# Naive check runs checks once a minute to see if either of the processes exited.
# This illustrates part of the heavy lifting you need to do if you want to run
# more than one service in a container. The container exits with an error
# if it detects that either of the processes has exited.
# Otherwise it loops forever, waking up every 60 seconds

while sleep 60; do
  ps aux |grep escomled_data_grid |grep -q -v grep
  PROCESS_1_STATUS=$?
  ps aux |grep escomled_dirwatcher |grep -q -v grep
  PROCESS_2_STATUS=$?
  ps aux |grep escomled_startmap |grep -q -v grep
  PROCESS_3_STATUS=$?
  ps aux |grep escomled_ml |grep -q -v grep
  PROCESS_4_STATUS=$?
  # If the greps above find anything, they exit with 0 status
  # If they are not both 0, then something is wrong
  if [ $PROCESS_1_STATUS -ne 0 -o $PROCESS_2_STATUS -ne 0 -o $PROCESS_3_STATUS -ne 0 -o $PROCESS_4_STATUS -ne 0 ]; then
    echo "One of the processes has already exited."
    exit 1
  fi
done
```

although most likely you would need to modify the grep conditions in the while loop to accurately match whatever processes your scripts are starting. Then assuming you named the script 'wrapper.sh'

you place the following lines in your Dockerfile:
COPY wrapper.sh /EscomledML/MLScripts/wrapper.sh
ENTRYPOINT ["EscomledML/MLScripts/wrapper.sh"]

Personally I would suggest using `supervisored` rather than wrapper script, but it's up to you.

Comment: `/wrapper.sh: line 50: syntax error: unexpected "done" (expecting "then")`

Comment: The sample script I provided has a comment on line 50, so I do not know how to help you. I would suggest using `supervisored` anyway.